# Use a Value from a textbox in Access to a stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, pass-through

I am hoping that someone could please hep me with this problem.

I am using Access as a front end system with linked tables to SQL Server Management Studio, using ODBC.
This has made the database run slow, so I am trying to convert the Access queries in to Stored procedures in SSMS, and then run them as pass through queries in Access. This has worked great so far, and the queries that I have converted are running very fast.

However I have only converted the queries that do not require user chosen variables within Access. These are the ones that I am now having difficulty with.

For example, let's say I have a simple table in SSMS called [Names] consisting of [First Name], [Surname]

I can run the following stored procedure, named [Search], to return all names:

```
SELECT [First name], [Surname]
FROM [Names]
```

I can execute this stored procedure in the front end Access as a pass through query, and it does return all the records.

However, within the front end Access database, I have a form called [Search], with a textbox named "SearchFirstName". When the user manually types in 'Anthony' into the textbox, I would like it to to take the value from the textbox, and use it as part of the stored procedure to limit the results, as follows:

```
SELECT [First name], [Surname]
FROM [Names]
WHERE [First Name] = [Forms]![Search]![SearchFirstName]
```

I have searched for help, but I am becoming stuck. I think I need Access to set the textbox value as a parameter, which can then be used in SSMS.

The avenue that I have found which might work from another article is below, however I am not sure how/where I would need to implement it:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qPass") .SQL = "exec SalesGeneralSearch " & strSearch Set Me.MyListBox.RowSource = .OpenRecordset End If
```

If anyone could help, I would be so grateful

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into using ADODB.Recordsets for executing your SPs?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would it be possible if you could provide a bit more guidance, and that way I can hopefully google my way through the rest of it? Thank you

Comment: I've added an example of what I do when accessing SQL SPs from MS Access VBA. I have a very similar setup to yours, an Access front end, and a SQL Server backend. This has been a reliable method for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I execute SQL stored procedures in MS Access (VBA):

```
'ADODB connection (to SQL Server).
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
With cnn
    .ConnectionString = {your ODBC connection to SQL Server}
    .CommandTimeout = 30 '<-- optional, but speeds up connection problems.
    .Open
End With

'ADODB command (reference to SQL stored procedure)
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandText = {your_stored_procedure_name}
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Parameters.Refresh
End With

'Add your SP parameter(s)...
cmd.Parameters("@param_name").value = {your_value}

'ADODB recordset to capture your SP results.
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .CacheSize = 1
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .Open cmd
End With

'Loop through the resultset...
Do While Not rs.EOF

    'Work with your resultset here...

rs.MoveNext '<-- don't forget this!
Loop

'Cleanup.
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, I shall give this a try

Comment: Might be a little more than what you're looking for, but it works.

Comment: That's what I was looking for for some days. RS.Open CMD did the trick. That was worth a +1. Just a remark: Change "RetVal" with "RS" in the With-Statement. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Dim strName   as string
dim rst    as DAO.RecordSet
strName = [Forms]![Search]![SearchFirstName]
strSQL = "SELECT [First name], [Surname] FROM [Names] WHERE SurName = '" & strName & "'"

CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPTQuery").SQL = strSQL
```

' now open report based on above.

Or for a reocrdset, go:

```
dim rst    as DAO.RecordSet
set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("MyPTQuery")
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you so much for getting back to me. I have had a few days now to work on the solution you provided, and I have also looked at similar solutions that you have provided elsewhere. I can't thank you enough, as I have almost sorted my problem. I have put the new code as an answer, and was wondering if you had any suggestions as to how I could add more than one variable

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an update to my original question. By using the help from here, I have managed to get the query to work for one variable. It works as follows:

**SQL Stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ZSearch]

@First varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN

SELECT [First name], [Surname]
FROM [Names]
Where  ([First Name] LIKE '%' + @First + '%')
END
```

**Then in Access, I have a pass through query which is:**

```
exec [ZSearch]
```

**Then Finally, on my form, I have a button which runs the following VB on click:**

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Dim First As String

First = [Forms]![Search]![SearchFirstName]

   
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
    .SQL = "exec ZSearch " & First
'Debug.Print .SQL
    Set rst = .OpenRecordset()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPassR"
End With
End Sub
```

As I say this works really well. It gets the results that I want it too. However, I would also like to add extra search variables, for example SURNAME. I would also need it to work, if any of the text boxes in Access were null, or somehow set their default value to a wildcard.

I have tried the following

**SQL Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ZSearch]

@First varchar(100),
@Second varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN

SELECT [First name], [Surname]
FROM [Names]
Where  ([First Name] LIKE '%' + @First + '%') and ([Surname] LIKE '%' + @Second + '%')
END
```

**Then in Access, I have a pass through query which is:**

```
exec [ZSearch]
```

**Then Finally, on my form, I have a button which runs the following VB on click:**

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Dim First As String

First = [Forms]![Search]![SearchFirstName]
Second = [Forms]![Search]![SearchSurname]

   
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
    .SQL = "exec ZSearch " & First & Second
'Debug.Print .SQL
    Set rst = .OpenRecordset()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPassR"
End With
End Sub
```

However, when I try adding the second variable it does not work, and the vba debugger says 'Compile Error'

I am hoping that it is something simple which I am doing wrong